# detecting the memory page size

Tags: c++, c, memory, operating-system, hardware

Is there a portable way to detect (programmatically) the memory page size using C or C++ code ?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: No there isn't because C and C++ exist also for platforms without virtual memory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since [`Boost`](http://www.boost.org/) is a pretty portable library you could use [`mapped_region::get_page_size()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/mapped_region.html#id813730-bb) function to retrieve the memory page size.

As for C++ Standard it gives no such a possibility.

Comment: I'm using Boost 1.81.0 on Windows, and this seems to return SYSTEM_INFO::dwAllocationGranularity rather than dwPageSize, incorrectly giving 65536 instead of 4096

Answer (score 17):

C doesn't know anything about memory pages. On posix systems you can use `long pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);`

Answer (score 12):

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, C++. Get the page size in bytes.

```
int main()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;

    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);

    printf("%s %d\n\n", "PageSize[Bytes] :", sysInfo.dwPageSize);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Across operating systems, no.

On Linux systems:

```
#include <unistd.h>
long sz = sysconf (_SC_PAGESIZE);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is platform-specific. On Linux there's `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`, which also seems to be POSIX. A typical C library implements this using the auxiliary vector. If for some reason you don't have a C library or the auxiliary vector you could determine the page size like this:

```
size_t get_page_size(void)
{
    size_t n;
    char *p;
    int u;
    for (n = 1; n; n *= 2) {
        p = mmap(0, n * 2, PROT_NONE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
        if (p == MAP_FAILED)
            return -1;
        u = munmap(p + n, n);
        munmap(p, n * 2);
        if (!u)
            return n;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That's also POSIX, I think. It relies on there being some free memory, but it only needs two consecutive pages. It might be useful in some (weird) circumstances.

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing with the double `munmap`?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely platform dependent which address-ranges are mapped to which page-sizes. Further  the pagesize is not system-wide. You can allocate memory from different page-size regions according to the use case. And you can even have platforms without any virtual memory managment.

So, code handling this topic must be platform specific.

Comment: Disconnect between your explanation and the conclusion; applying the same logic would tell us that determining the size of a pointer is platform specific.

Answer (score -4):

I think this function helps.
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern void GetSystemInfo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);

Comment: Question says 'C', 'C++' and 'portable' and on top of that you managed to not even describe how to get from that to a page size.